# how to change the id value on each click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here I'm having a code where the working is on each click function a new row is generated and each having id value and from that id value i need to get the result of the another column in that row.

```
$("#addrow").click(function () {
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="description">' +
        '<select class="form-control select2" name="branch" id="branch_ids"">' +
        '<option value="">Choose Branch</option><?php foreach ($branch as $val) {?>' +
        '<option value="<?php echo $val->id; ?>"><?php echo $val->name; ?></option><?php } ?></select>' +
        '</td><td><textarea name="amount[]" id="amounts" class="cost textarea" required></textarea></td></tr>');

    $("#branch_ids").change(function () {
        var branch = $(this).val();
        var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>bills/get_corresponding_code";
        $.post(url, { branch: branch }, function (data) {
            $('#amounts').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Here only the first row is getting affected.

Comment: Because `id` attribute __MUST BE UNIQUE__

Comment: add rendered HTML as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Here only the first row is getting affected.* This is expected behaviors as Identifiers in must be unique.

However you can assign a CSS class to them i.e. *branch_ids* and [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind event handlers using the [Class Selector (".class")](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$("#addrow").click(function() {
    $(".item-row:last").after('<tr class="item-row"><td class="description">' +
            '<select class="form-control select2 branch_ids" name="branch">' +
            '<option value="">Choose Branch</option><?php foreach ($branch as $val) {?>' +
            '<option value="<?php echo $val->id; ?>"><?php echo $val->name; ?></option><?php } ?></select>' +
            '</td><td><textarea name="amount[]" class="cost textarea amounts" required></textarea></td></tr>');
});

$(doument).on('change', '.branch_ids', function() {
    var branch = $(this).val();
    var amount = $(this).closest('item-row').find('.amounts');

    var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>bills/get_corresponding_code";
    $.post(url, {
        branch: branch
    }, function(data) {
        amount.html(data);
    });
});
```

Note: In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

Comment: thanks for helping but by using your code result is not obtained

Comment: by using the code when one branch_ids is changed all the amount values are getting changed

Comment: @user_777, I have updated the snippet, You have to use CSS class with amount also and DOM traversal to target desired element